# Manage LXC containers from host in puppet

Tags: lxc, puppet

Is there any puppet modules for manage nodes in LXC containers from local host? E.g.: I have host with 50 LXC containers and I want to manage all those containers from host directly, not from another one LXC container with `puppetmaster`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily puppet modules for lxc itself. But there is good support for docket.

http://mizzy.org/blog/2013/03/24/1/

http://puppetlabs.com/podcasts/solomon-hykes-docker-and-rise-linux-containers